# replace the text in side the content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to replace the content inside the `em`. but it not work. Here the code

```
 <p>
 <em>
    <a href='/'>not</a>
    yes
    yes 
    yes
  </em>
  </p>
```

Here the out put is `not yes yes yes`
Here I want to remove text `yes` and i need output only text as `not`.
How may i do this. I am waiting for your valuable answer.
Thanks for your advice

Comment: Do you want to keep the `<a>` tag or just have the raw text `not`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all `yes`, you may do this :

```
$(function(){
   $('em').each(function(){
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/yes/g, ''));
   });
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/EjJhv/)

If you want to remove all text nodes, you may do this :

```
$('em').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();​
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question, you need to make the selector you use specific to the `a` element. Try this:

```
alert($("em a").text()); // = not
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
$('em').text($('em a').text());
```

Anyway you need to load jquery or it will not work